# Receiver is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist

Tags: xcode, class, interface, forward

thanks for taking the time to read my problem and help me:)

I am building a TabView project and on tab 3 of the app I have a row of albums, in album 3, page 1 the nextButton takes the user to page 2 of the album. Page 2 has more buttons, including a backPage(get back to page 1) and a backButton(to go back to the album selection page).

ERROR:

```
A3Page2ViewController.m:92:49: Property 'view' cannot be found in forward class object 'A3Page1ViewController'
```

WARNING:

```
A3Page2ViewController.m:91:28: Receiver 'A3Page1ViewController' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist
```

I have searched this site and others and most of the answers are in relation to how @Class should be used in the header filw and #import ".h" should only be used in the .m file. I have checked my code and I was following the rules, so why does it still not work?

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE: This is the function(in A3Page2ViewController) that is apparently making the error...

```
-(IBAction)backPage:(id)sender
{
    a3Page1ViewController = [[A3Page1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3Page1ViewController"bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:a3Page1ViewController.view];

}
```

**Please note that when commented out, the app runs FINE all the views are loaded, all buttons including backButton work. When uncommented it just refuses to build, with the errors.**

Below I list both A3Page1ViewController and A3Page2ViewController both the .h and .m files.

You can see that I have the @class and #import ".h" in the correct places.

WEIRDNESS!!
I actually have the exact same code WORKING in the 2nd tab, I use it to switch between views with out any problem. SO WHY DOES IT NOT WORK HERE?!?!

**PLEASE HELP I AM STUCK ATM AND I DON'T KNOW WHY:/**

A3Page1ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class A3Page2ViewController;
@class ThirdViewController;
@class A3P1;
@class A3P2;
@class A3P3;


@interface A3Page1ViewController : UIViewController  {

    A3Page2ViewController*a3Page2ViewController;
    ThirdViewController*thirdViewController;

    A3P1*A3P1;
    A3P2*A3P2;
    A3P3*A3P3;


    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button2;
    UIButton *button3;

    UIButton *nextButton;
    UIButton *backButton;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3Page2ViewController *a3Page2ViewController;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet ThirdViewController *thirdViewController;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3P1 *a3P1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3P2 *a3P2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3P3 *a3P3;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *logoLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *copyrightLabel;


@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *nextButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;

-(IBAction)FirstButton:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)SecondButton:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ThirdButton:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;


@end
```

A3Page1ViewController.m

```
#import "A3Page1ViewController.h"
#import "FXLabel.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "A3Page2ViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "A3P1.h"
#import "A3P2.h"
#import "A3P3.h"



@implementation A3Page1ViewController

@synthesize  a3Page2ViewController,thirdViewController,a3P1 ,a3P2 ,a3P3 , logoLabel, descriptionLabel, button1,button2,button3,nextButton,backButton, copyrightLabel;


-(UILabel*)createLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andFontSize:(float)fontSize andText:(NSString*)text
{
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
    //[label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setText:text];
    return label;
}

-(IBAction)FirstButton:(id)sender
{
    a3P1 = [[A3P1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3P1"bundle:nil];  
    [self.view addSubview:a3P1.view];
}

-(IBAction)SecondButton:(id)sender
{

    a3P2 = [[A3P2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3P2"bundle:nil];  
    [self.view addSubview:a3P2.view];

}

-(IBAction)ThirdButton:(id)sender
{
    a3P3 = [[A3P3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3P3"bundle:nil];  
    [self.view addSubview:a3P3.view];   

}

-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender
{
    thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdView"bundle:nil];  
    [self.view addSubview:thirdViewController.view];
}
-(IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender
{
    a3Page2ViewController = [[A3Page2ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3Page2ViewController"bundle:nil];  
    [self.view addSubview:a3Page2ViewController.view];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad  
{
    //CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}





/*
 // The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView {
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

A3Page2ViewController.h

```
@class A3Page1ViewController;
@class ThirdViewController;
@class A3P10;
@class A3P11;
@class A3P12;



@interface A3Page2ViewController : UIViewController  {

    A3Page1ViewController*a3Page1ViewController;
    ThirdViewController*thirdViewController;
    A3P10*a3P10;
    A3P11*a3P11;
    A3P12*a3P12;


    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button2;
    UIButton *button3;

    UIButton *backButton;
    UIButton *backPage;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3Page1ViewController *a3Page1ViewController;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet ThirdViewController *thirdViewController;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3P10 *a3P10;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3P11 *a3P11;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet A3P12 *a3P12;


@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *backPage;

-(IBAction)FirstButton:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)SecondButton:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ThirdButton:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)backPage:(id)sender;

@end
```

A3Page2ViewController.m

```
#import "A3Page1ViewController.h"
#import "FXLabel.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "A3Page2ViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "A3P10.h"
#import "A3P11.h"
#import "A3P12.h"


@implementation A3Page2ViewController

@synthesize  thirdViewController,a3Page1ViewController,a3P10 ,a3P11 ,a3P12, backButton,backPage, button1,button2,button3;


-(UILabel*)createLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andFontSize:(float)fontSize andText:(NSString*)text
{
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
    //  [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setText:text];
    return label;
}

-(IBAction)FirstButton:(id)sender
{
    a3P10 = [[A3P10 alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3P10"bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:a3P10.view];
}

-(IBAction)SecondButton:(id)sender
{

    a3P11 = [[A3P11 alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3P11"bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:a3P11.view];

}

-(IBAction)ThirdButton:(id)sender
{
    a3P12 = [[A3P12 alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3P12"bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:a3P12.view];

}


-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender
{
    thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdView"bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:thirdViewController.view];

}
-(IBAction)backPage:(id)sender
{
//*****Alleged Error/Warning causing code=[********
    a3Page1ViewController = [[A3Page1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"A3Page1ViewController"bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:a3Page1ViewController.view];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


/*
 // The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView {
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: One problem is that in `A3Page2ViewController` you're synthesizing nine buttons but only declaring three.

Comment: I cut some of the code out to make the post that much shorter. Thanks for spotting that. I don't want to cause more confusion in what is already a lot of code to read:)

Comment: Since nothing looks obviously wrong, I wonder if it's something odd in one of the files you're importing.  If you comment out the imports, variables, and methods in A3Page2ViewController.m that have nothing to do with `a3Page1ViewController`, does the error go away?

Comment: Ok I just commented out all of the imports, variables, methods from the header and main. Except A3Page1ViewController.
But it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I don't know the answer.  I just tried the same thing by copying your code into two new classes in a test project, stripping out the unrelated .h files, and I don't get the error that you're seeing.

Comment: Seriously, thanks for looking mate!! Doubly annoying since it works for you and the rest of my code:/
Anychance you could reccommend some code to replace that? Basically that button press should take it 'back to the previous page'.
Thanks again x

Comment: I suppose it's possible that there are non-printing junk characters in your file someplace.  If I can paste it OK from your question, can **you** paste from your question into a clean file and have it work?

Comment: Worth a shot, but no cigar I'm afraid=[ (didn't work)

Comment: Clean the build and restart Xcode?

Comment: I quit Xcode, reopened and cleaned. Still doesn't work.
Was a good shout though as it's been open for 2+hours now.